# Check date range in java without time AND using jodatime

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a date supplied by the user and of course today's date.
I'm attempting to verify that the difference between the 2 days is at least 2 weeks.  I've done this using standard libraries - but I'm attempting to do this using jodaTime and I'm having some difficulty.

```
// BAD CODE - doesn't work       
// NOTE: getUserSuppliedDate() returns an instance of java.sql.Date
// Also assume that validation prior to this call has been run that 
// validates that the userSuppliedDate comes AFTER today's date - not sure if 
// that is relevant in the context I'm attempting to use these particular jodaTime APIs.
DateTime jodaStartDate = new DateTime(getUserSuppliedDate());
if (Days.daysBetween(jodaStartDate, DateTime.now()).isLessThan(Days.days(14))) {
    System.out.println("Bad user.  You have chosen...poorly.");
}
else {
   System.out.println("Well done user. You have supplied wisely.");
}

// GOOD CODE  ---- ?  Help =)
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code gives you the wrong result because the dates supplied to `Days.daysBetween()` are in the wrong order. Since you specified that the user supplied date comes *after* the current date, your approach will result in a *negative* number of days.

It will work correctly if you switch the order, putting the earliest date first.

Compare the following two:

```
DateTime jodaStartDate = new DateTime().withYear(2018)
                                       .withMonthOfYear(7)
                                       .withDayOfMonth(5); // 15 days from now

System.out.println(Days.daysBetween(jodaStartDate, DateTime.now())); // "P-15D"    
System.out.println(Days.daysBetween(DateTime.now(), jodaStartDate)); // "P15D"
```

In the first case, -15 days will evaluate to less than 14 days.

Using weeks instead of days, you'd run into the same problem:

```
System.out.println(Weeks.weeksBetween(jodaStartDate, DateTime.now())); // "P-2W"
System.out.println(Weeks.weeksBetween(DateTime.now(), jodaStartDate)); // "P2W"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation + showing me where I was going wrong and not just suggesting alternatives.